# Vb.Net Sort 3x One Dimensional Arrays

Tags: arrays, vb.net, sorting, icomparable

I have 3 one dimensional arrays.
Each contains information that corresponds to the other 2 arrays.
e.g Array 1 contains a customer first name
Array 2 contains a customer last name
Array 3 contains the customer phone number.

This is not my actual example but is easiest to explain.
How do I sort all three arrays so that they are sorted in order by say customer last name.
If Mr Smith is sorted and has moved from position 10 to position 5 in the lastname array, I would expect his phone number and first name to also be in position 5 in the respective arrays.

I am dealing with arrays with 10,000's of items so I would like to avoid looping (my current method) as this is incredibly slow.

Hoping to use the array.sort methods.

Can someone help me?

Ok - So I have tried to use a new data Type but am still at a loss how I can instantly filter using this. Below is my sample code which has a couple of issues. If someone can resolve - it would love to learn how you did it.

The purpose of the code is to return an array containing grouped issues.
For simplicity I have assumed in the example that each constant found is an issue.
If an issue is found, combine it with other issues found on that same worksheet.
e.g The number 2 is found in both cells A1 and A2 on sheet 1. The array should return A1:A2.
If the issues are found in A1 on sheet 1 and A2 in sheet 2, two seperate array entries would be returned.

[Test File and Code Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qnnma14vyli7do1/Filter%20Example.xlsm)

```
Public Type Issues
    ws_Sheet As Integer
    rng_Range As String
    s_Formula As String
    s_Combined As String
    d_ItemCount As Double
End Type

Sub IssuesFound()

Dim MyIssues() As Issues
Dim i_SheetCount As Integer
Dim s_Formula As String
Dim rng_Range As Range
Dim d_IssueCounter As Double
Dim s_SearchFor As String
Dim a_TempArray() As Issues
Dim d_InsertCounter As Double


d_IssueCounter = -1

' Loop All Sheets Using A Counter Rather Than For Each
For i_SheetCount = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count

    ' Loop all Constants On Worksheet
    For Each rng_Range In Sheets(i_SheetCount).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23)

        If d_IssueCounter = -1 Then
            ' First Time and Issue Is Found, Start Recording In An Array
            d_IssueCounter = d_IssueCounter + 1
            ReDim MyIssues(0)
            MyIssues(0).ws_Sheet = i_SheetCount
            MyIssues(0).rng_Range = rng_Range.AddressLocal
            MyIssues(0).s_Formula = rng_Range.Value
            MyIssues(0).s_Combined = i_SheetCount & "#" & rng_Range.Value
            MyIssues(0).d_ItemCount = 0

        Else
            ' Going To Look For Issues Found On The Same Sheet with The Same Constant Value
            s_SearchFor = i_SheetCount & "#" & rng_Range.Value

            ' HELP HERE: Need To Ideally Return Whether The Above Search Term Exists In The Array
            ' Without looping, and I want to return the position in the array if the item is found
             a_TempArray = MyIssues 'Filter(MyIssues.s_Combined, s_SearchFor, True, vbTextCompare)

            If IsVarArrayEmpty(a_TempArray) = True Then
                ' New Issue Found - Increase Counter By + 1
                d_IssueCounter = d_IssueCounter + 1

                ' Increase The Array By 1
                ReDim Preserve MyIssues(d_IssueCounter)

                ' Record The Information About The Constant Found. Sheet Number, Constant, Range, and also a combined string for searching and the array position
                MyIssues(0).ws_Sheet = i_SheetCount
                MyIssues(0).rng_Range = rng_Range.AddressLocal
                MyIssues(0).s_Formula = rng_Range.Value
                MyIssues(0).s_Combined = i_SheetCount & "#" & rng_Range.Value
                MyIssues(0).d_ItemCount = 0

            Else
                ' Get The Array Position Where Other Issues With The Same Worksheet and Constant are Stored
                d_InsertCounter = a_TempArray.d_ItemCount

                ' Add The New Found Constant To The Range Already Containing The Same Constants on This Worksheet
                MyIssues(d_InsertCounter).rng_Range = Union(rng_Range, Range(MyIssues(d_InsertCounter).rng_Range)).AddressLocal

            End If

        End If
    Next

Next

End Sub

Function IsVarArrayEmpty(ByRef anArray As Issues)

Dim i As Integer

On Error Resume Next
    i = UBound(anArray, 1)
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        IsVarArrayEmpty = False
    Else
        IsVarArrayEmpty = True
    End If

End Function
```

[Sample Test File and Code Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qnnma14vyli7do1/Filter%20Example.xlsm)

Comment: Why are you even using arrays? Why not types?

Comment: Or classes. Dim Smith as New Person, Smith.Phone = #, Smith.Address = # etc.? I know it sucks to get responses that don't answer your question but 3 related arrays are strange. Also, why not a 2d array or a table?

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. You will have to excuse my limited knowledge of VBA. I have not used types before.
The purpose of using arrays was so that I could use the array.methods to quickly check whether an item was present in one of the arrays, and if it is update its corresponding item in one of the other arrays. Can I do this with types?

I want to avoid looping through thousands of items to check if an item exists in the data set.

Comment: See my adjusted question. Even with types how do i filter or find a record without looping?

Answer (score 2):

As suggested, you should not be using concurrent arrays at all.  You should be defining a type with three properties and then creating a single array or collection of that type.

To answer your question though, there is no way to sort three arrays in concert but there is a way to sort two.  What that means is that you can create a copy of the array that you want to use as keys and then use the copy to sort one of the other arrays and the original to sort the other.  Check out the documentation for the Array.Copy overload that takes two arrays as arguments.

That said, copying the array and then sorting twice is a big overhead so you may not gain much, if anything, from this method.  Better to just do it the right way in the first place, i.e. use a single array of a complex type rather than concurrent arrays of simple types.  It's not 1960 any more, after all.

Comment: + 1 Didn't know you were in SO as well John :)